# Use of undeclared identifier 'AIRGoogleMapOverlay' in AIRGoogleMapOverlayManager even after #import "AIRGoogleMapOverlay.h"

Tags: ios, xcode, google-maps, react-native, undeclared-identifier

I am getting `Use of undeclared identifier 'AIRGoogleMapOverlay'` error when I am trying to run my react native project through Xcode. I am actually trying to open the app on my iPhone and thats when I encounter this error. If I simply say react-native run-ios, it builds and launches the app on simulator. I am trying to extract current device location which I can't do using a simulator.

The error occurs in the AirGoogleMapOverlayManager.m file which exists in the react-native-google-maps package.

**AIRGoogleMapOverlay.h**

```
#ifdef HAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <GoogleMaps/GoogleMaps.h>
#import <React/RCTBridge.h>
#import "AIRMapCoordinate.h"
#import "AIRGoogleMap.h"

@interface AIRGoogleMapOverlay : UIView

@property (nonatomic, strong) GMSGroundOverlay *overlay;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *imageSrc;
@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) UIImage *overlayImage;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *boundsRect;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) GMSCoordinateBounds *overlayBounds;

@property (nonatomic, weak) RCTBridge *bridge;

@end

#endif
```

**AIRGoogleMapOverlay.m**

```
#ifdef HAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS

#import "AIRGoogleMapOverlay.h"

#import <React/RCTEventDispatcher.h>
#import <React/RCTImageLoader.h>
#import <React/RCTUtils.h>
#import <React/UIView+React.h>

@interface AIRGoogleMapOverlay()
  @property (nonatomic, strong, readwrite) UIImage *overlayImage;
  @property (nonatomic, readwrite) GMSCoordinateBounds *overlayBounds;
@end

@implementation AIRGoogleMapOverlay {
  RCTImageLoaderCancellationBlock _reloadImageCancellationBlock;
  CLLocationCoordinate2D _southWest;
  CLLocationCoordinate2D _northEast;
}

- (instancetype)init
{
  if ((self = [super init])) {
    _overlay = [[GMSGroundOverlay alloc] init];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)setImageSrc:(NSString *)imageSrc
{
  NSLog(@">>> SET IMAGESRC: %@", imageSrc);
  _imageSrc = imageSrc;

  if (_reloadImageCancellationBlock) {
    _reloadImageCancellationBlock();
    _reloadImageCancellationBlock = nil;
  }

  __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
  _reloadImageCancellationBlock = [_bridge.imageLoader loadImageWithURLRequest:[RCTConvert NSURLRequest:_imageSrc]
                                                                          size:weakSelf.bounds.size
                                                                         scale:RCTScreenScale()
                                                                       clipped:YES
                                                                    resizeMode:RCTResizeModeCenter
                                                                 progressBlock:nil
                                                              partialLoadBlock:nil
                                                               completionBlock:^(NSError *error, UIImage *image) {
                                                                 if (error) {
                                                                   NSLog(@"%@", error);
                                                                 }
                                                                 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                                                   NSLog(@">>> IMAGE: %@", image);
                                                                   weakSelf.overlayImage = image;
                                                                   weakSelf.overlay.icon = image;
                                                                 });
                                                               }];

}

- (void)setBoundsRect:(NSArray *)boundsRect
{
  _boundsRect = boundsRect;

  _southWest = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([boundsRect[1][0] doubleValue], [boundsRect[0][1] doubleValue]);
  _northEast = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([boundsRect[0][0] doubleValue], [boundsRect[1][1] doubleValue]);

  _overlayBounds = [[GMSCoordinateBounds alloc] initWithCoordinate:_southWest
                                                        coordinate:_northEast];

  _overlay.bounds = _overlayBounds;
}

@end

#endif
```

And here is where I get the error, in AIRGoogleMapOverlayManager

```
#import "AIRGoogleMapOverlayManager.h"
#import "AIRGoogleMapOverlay.h"

@interface AIRGoogleMapOverlayManager()

@end

@implementation AIRGoogleMapOverlayManager

- (UIView *)view
{
  AIRGoogleMapOverlay *overlay = [AIRGoogleMapOverlay new]; ERROR-Use of  undeclared identifier 'AIRGoogleMApOverlay'
  overlay.bridge = self.bridge; ERROR-Use of  undeclared identifier 'overlay'
  return overlay; ERROR-Use of  undeclared identifier 'overlay'
  return 0;
}

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

RCT_REMAP_VIEW_PROPERTY(bounds, boundsRect, NSArray)
RCT_REMAP_VIEW_PROPERTY(image, imageSrc, NSString)

@end
```

I know that solving the first will get rid of all 3 errors. Also I am running xcworkspace, not xcodeproj.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I added `HAVE_GOOGLE_MAPS=1` to the preprocessor macros, all the AIRGoogleMapOverlay related errors were gone.

This needs to be added for both **Debug** and **Release** in case someone is wondering why they are getting this error while trying to create an offline bundle.

Comment: Thanks! I had mine set for Debug and not Release.. worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

You might need a bridging header.

Create a file in your project, named for instance AIRGoogleMapOverlay-Bridging-Header.h

and put

```
#import "AIRGoogleMapOverlay.h"
```

in it.

Finally, add the header file in your Build settings like below, depending on the environment you need it to be set up.

[image]

Comment: @Diphase I have done the same. But getting the following error. AirMapCoordinate.h not found in the Pods->Development Pods-> react-native-maps ->AirGoogleMapPolyline.h,